# reputation limit for approving edits

Tags: feature-request

Someone suggested an edit to one of my answers, i was surprised that as the original author of the answer i'm still apparently bound by the reputation limit on approving the edit. This seems wrong to me, i get that the limit should apply to edits to other posts, but it seems like i should be able to aprove an edit to my answer regardless of reputation score. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/460/144

Comment: related is the fact that no-one seems to currently have the rep to approve edits.

Comment: ...and yet they are being approved. I guess some of the StackExchange super users are priming the pumps...

Comment: yeah, i saw a flurry of edits get approved this morning, not sure who it was.

Comment: @metadaddy You're currently in the caring hands of the [community team](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good feature for the network in general. I'm pretty sure right now edits are being approved by the StackExchange community managers, though as well as incorporating the ability to accept edits on your own questions, I'd like to propose that edit rights work across sites on the network...

I think good editing skills are not necessarily related to the knowledge or skills that tie directly to the central topic of a Stack Exchange site. I edit and fix quite a few questions on Stackoverflow, and keep getting surprised when I see the message about approval on here!